# The width parameter of the jqGrid edit modal breaks the other parameters

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

When I add width to the edit modal in jqGrid, the parameters after it (i.e., add:false, `closeAfterEdit: true`, etc.) stop working.  I've tried it in different places, and it doesn't work.

```js
jQuery("#prodgrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {width: 1000},{edit: true, add: false, del: false, search: false}, {closeAfterEdit: true},  {closeAfterAdd: true});
```

FYI:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use wrong options of `navGrid`. If you examine [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) you will see that the position of the parameters which you use is wrong. The correct will be

```js
$("#prodgrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    {add: false, del: false, search: false},
    {closeAfterEdit: true, width: 1000},
    {closeAfterAdd: true, width: 1000});
```

(you can skip `edit: true` because it's already default value).

I see that you use free jqGrid. It makes specifying of jqGrid options easier. First of all you can skip `'#pager'`. In the case jqGrid will just use the pager which you already specified during creating of the grid. Seconds you can specify `page: true` in the option of the grid instead of usage `pager: '#pager'`. You will don't need to create empty `<div id="pager"></div>` in the case. By usage `page: true` free jqGrid will create the corresponding div automatically. Moreover the options of `'navGrid'` are divided in independent parts: the `navGrid` option `{edit: true, add: false, del: false, search: false}` and the options of form editing: `{closeAfterEdit: true, width: 1000}` and `{closeAfterAdd: true, width: 1000}`. Free jqGrid allows to specify the options directly during creating the grid and then use simplified form of the call of `navGrid`:

```js
$("#prodgrid").jqGrid({
    // here there are all other standard option which you already use
    pager: true,
    navOptions: {add: false, del: false, search: false},
    formEditing: {closeAfterEdit: true, closeAfterAdd: true, width: 1000}
}).jqGrid("navGrid");
```

You can read more about the style of coding the option of jqGrid [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods). I personally like much more named parameter as positioned parameter because everybody can better read the code.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm going to test what you sent me.  i think I got lost in the documentation for the different versions which is unclear to me.  Does the documentation you referenced indicate the version of jqgrid?  I'm not finding it.

Comment: @Robin: You are welcome! [The documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) of jqGrid describes the options of `navGrid`. `navGrid` just creates the buttons in the navigator bar. If the user click on "Edit" or "Add" button then `navGrid` calls [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) method with parameters `prmEdit` or `prmAdd`. If the user click Delete button `navGrid` calls [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#delgridrow) method and so on.

Comment: @Robin: Free jqGrid hold compatibility with old versions of jqGrid, but it provides the possibility to use simplified form of specifying of options and callbacks of `editGridRow`, `delGridRow` and other methods. It allows to write more short and more readable code like in the example from [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods#solution-of-the-problem-in-free-jqgrid-48).

Comment: I do not see the same position of parameters you used in the wiki documentation you referenced.  I don't see closeAfterEdit or width parameter on that wiki documentation page, either.

Comment: @Robin: I tried to explain you in my previous comments that 3-th and 4-th parameters of `navGrid` (`prmEdit` and `prmAdd`) are objects with parameters of `editGridRow` method. So the objects can contains any  [property](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) or [callback](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) described in the documentation of the method [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow).

Comment: @Robin: See the statement "**prmEdit, prmAdd, prmDel, prmSearch, prmView are objects which holds the parameters and events for a particular action in Form editing**" in the documentation of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition).